# Magic numbers in formulas

Tags: java

It's a well established convention that magic numbers should be avoided. But what about magic numbers in complex, conditional formulas? For example:

```all
int result = 0;
if (level <= 50) {
    result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * (100 - level) / 50);
}
else if (level <= 68 && level > 50) {
    result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * (150 - level) / 100);
}
else if (level <= 98 && level > 68) {
    result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * ((1911 - 10 * level) / 3) / 500);
}
else if (level < 100 && level > 98) {
    result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * (160 - level) / 100);
}
return result;
```

In this case, would it be better to just say "avoid magic numbers when possible"? I am also using CheckStyle in eclipse to help show me where I may have missed an actual magic number. However, there is no way to disable the check for some numbers and not others.

Comment: most of the formulas displayed here are still very similar, why not replace values with variables and assign them in if checks.

Comment: In this particular place you MUST avoid magic numbers. No one except of you is able to say why do you need `1911 - 10 * level` etc. What is 1911 ? what is 68? nobody knows

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. IMO though, if the magic numbers are integral to business logic, then it should be fine to let it be. Check this for a more elaborate discussion of the topic: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx

Comment: After thinking about your magic umber I agree with Konstantin Salikhov - they don't seem to be magic numbers in a generic way. They just seem to be constants for a specific purpose of your case or idea.

Comment: I didn't come up with the equations, and I don't know what the numbers mean. It is an equation used in a video game to calculate the amount of experience to go to the next level defined [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience)

Comment: What are magic numbers?

Comment: @Zymus the fact that you don't know what the numbers mean answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

I think all magic numbers should be either declared as constants or properly documented.

Declaration with documenting is preferred.

Otherwise it is not clear for a developer what these numbers are and why are they there.

Comment: I agree. Making "unusual appearances" a constant with a well-explaining name is a good start. Anyhow they should be documented in code

Answer (score 2):

Not only does this need to replace magic numbers with named constants, I'd suggest some named intermediate variables.  For example, what the heck is the meaning of `((1911 - 10 * level) / 3) / 500)` ?  That should be assigned to a variable with a meaningful name.  Is this Social Security payments and ages?

The fact that OP doesn't understand the numbers nor the equation answers this question.  How is he going to support this code?

Answer (score 0):

I would try simplifying the code first.

```
int l3 = level * level * level;

return level <= 50 ? l3 * (100 - level) / 50 :
        level <= 68 ? l3 * (150 - level) / 100 :
                level <= 98 ? l3 * ((1911 - 10 * level) / 3) / 500 :
                        level < 100 ? l3 * (160 - level) / 100 : 0;
```

Then I would look at why the result is 0 if the level >= 100.

Since this appears arbitrary, it can be hard to explain the magic numbers because you might have made them up, but equally you might find you can simplify the formula to one easier to calculate and explain but still has the desired shape.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat a matter of style and taste. A general advice is: use magic numbers when it is obvious from the context what you mean and why, or when their use itself is their definition -- that is, when there is no other explanation of what and why the number means. For example, if I define a function:

```
0 if x < 28 else 1
```

and there is nothing more specific to say about this number than "the threshold that I use to define my function" AND there is no other constant equal to 28 in your program and never will be, then you probably can leave it as is.

In your case, you probably define these thresholds by this formula, and there is nothing to say about them, then you can leave them as is.

If you can give the number a name and/or comment on why this number has this value, then it's always better to use a name:

```
var age  = 52; // my age
var code = 52; // my country's long distance code
```

Even when you have nothing to say about a number, it's always better to give it a name because if you have two such numbers, you will later not know whether they are independent or not. Even if now you don't have them equal, someday you probably will. In the example above, next year I will turn 53 and will have to modify the formula:

```
a = 52 * x + y + z + 52;
```

but which of the two is my age and which is the code? A year ago when I wrote this program it was

```
a = 51 * x + y + z + 52;
```

and it was obvious for me which is my age and which is my code, but not after I turned 52 and modified the program accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

you can try something similar to below: (its not refined, try to come up with one single formula/equation and substitute values in the variables as per checks)

```
int d = 1;
    int x = 3;
    int l = 1;
    int f = 1;
    int y = 0;

    if (level <= 50) {
        y = 100;
        d = 50;
    } else if (level <= 68 && level > 50) {
        y = 150;
        d = 100;
    } else if (level <= 98 && level > 68) {
        y = 1911;
        l = 10;
        f = 500;
        d=3;
    } else if (level < 100 && level > 98) {
        y = 160;
        d = 100;
    }
    return (int) (Math.pow(level, x) * ((y - level * l) / d) / f);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rafael mentioned, Magic numbers should be declared as constants and properly documented,

Adding one more thing to improve it, You are performing same operation three time (I am not sure what you are doing in your 3rd if condition, you can consider it four time if these have same context) so you can declare a method to improve readability of code having many magic number as following,

```
public int calcResult(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
   return (int)(Math.pow(level, arg1) * (arg2 - level) / arg3);
}

.... 

int result = 0;
if (level <= 50) {
    result = calcResult(3,100,50); // these can be replaced with constants.
}
else if (level <= 68 && level > 50) {
    result = calcResult(3, 150, 100);
}
else if (level <= 98 && level > 68) {
    result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * ((1911 - 10 * level) / 3) / 500); // You can also change this accordingly.
}
else if (level < 100 && level > 98) {
    result = calcResult(3, 160, 100);
}
return result;
```

Above code is more readable for user, as same operations are being performed by a method. Replacing magic numbers with constants will improve it more.

Comment: As I said in the OP, I didn't come up with the equations, and I don't know what the numbers mean. It is an equation used in a video game to calculate the amount of experience to go to the next level defined [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience)

Comment: @Zymus Link is helpful, good finding. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Programming is not something that has hard-and-fast rules. Programming is all about making trade-offs. And to make *good* trade-offs, we have good practices which are agreed upon. Frowning upon magic numbers is one of them.

That does not mean magic numbers should always be avoided. The following example is a stupid use of avoiding magic numbers practice:

```
final int ONE = 1; // as if the value of 1 is going to change in the future
```

But this would be acceptable:

```
final int BITS_TO_SHIFT = 1;
// and further down in the code
int shifted_value = value >> BITS_TO_SHIFT;
```

Having said that, let's see if the code you supplied really *does* need magic numbers:

1. We can move the cube magic number to a constant:

   ```
   final int CUTOFF_1 =  50;
   final int CUTOFF_2 =  68;
   final int CUTOFF_3 =  98;
   final int MAX      = 100;


   int result = 0;
   if (level <= CUTOFF_1) {
       result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * (100 - level) / 50);
   }
   else if (level <= CUTOFF_2 && level > CUTOFF_1) {
       result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * (150 - level) / 100);
   }
   else if (level <= CUTOFF_3 && level > CUTOFF_2) {
       result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * ((1911 - 10 * level) / 3) / 500);
   }
   else if (level < MAX && level > CUTOFF_3) {
       result = (int) (Math.pow(level, 3) * (160 - level) / 100);
   }
   return result;
   ```
2. I think that looks better. Only the constants need to be updated if a change of cutoff numbers happens. I am sure most of the other constants can be removed this way too. But without knowing what they are I cannot do anything.

Note that as a stranger, I see those magic numbers as a collection of arbitrary numbers. Wouldn't it be better to create constants with appropriate names that describe the purpose of the constant?

Comment: As I said in the OP, I didn't come up with the equations, and I don't know what the numbers mean. It is an equation used in a video game to calculate the amount of experience to go to the next level defined [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience)

Comment: Then it is almost guaranteed that in a future version of the game the level-up criteria will be changed. I think you should find some good names for constants.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to add a link in the javadoc to the web page as well as defining vague constants? That way the user at least knows I didn't create the numbers haphazardly.

Comment: Absolutely. I think the more documentation there is explaining the arbitrary values will be better.